# Not able to login by PuTTY Network Error

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, putty

I have reset the user ("sftuser"), after that I am unable to login to the server, its throwing an error when logging in using `putty`:

> PuTTY Network Error: Software caused connection abort

I am able to login to other users without any issue.

We don't have any LDAP mechanism to login to set the server its a local 
user.

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has PAM as yes.

Also for `sftp` we added the following configuration:

```
Match Group sftponly
       ChrootDiretory /ftp/sftpuser
       AllowTcpForwarding no
       ForceCommand internal-sftp
       X11Forwarding no
```

In `/etc/passwd`:

```
sftpuser:x:4008:5007::/ftp/sftpuser:/bin/bash
```

Permissions:

```
ls -ld /ftp/sftpuser
drwxr-xr-x 3 sftpuser sftponly 4096 Oct 27 18:40 /ftp/sftpuser

ls -ld /ftp
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Dec 16 12:27 /ftp
```

After we reset and login to the putty. We are getting a popup in putty as:

```
Putty Fatal Error
X Network error:Software caused connection abort
```

After we press OK in the popup the putty session becomes inactive.

Comment: server log will tell you more about the reason why the login was rejected.

Comment: You are trying to configure the account to only allow sftp access, and are verifying that your config works, or your are trying to setup the account to allow both ssh and sftp?